# How do insert lines of text into file after a particular line in unix

Tags: perl, unix, sed, edit

How do insert lines of text into file after a particular line in unix ?

Background: The file is an autogenerated textfile but I manually have to edit it every time it is regenerated to add in 4 additional lines after a particular line. I can gurantee that this line will always be in the file but I cannot guarantee excalty what line it will be on so I want the additional lines to be added on the basis of the position of this line rather than adding to a fixed rownumber. I want to automate this process as it is part of my build process.

I'm using Mac OSX so I can make use of unix comand line tools, but Im not very familiar with such tools and cannot work out how to do this.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the solution, although I havent managed to get them working yet:

I tried Sed solution

```
sed -i '/<string>1.0</string>/ a <key>CFBundleHelpBookFolder</key>\
<string>SongKongHelp</string>\
<key>CFBundleHelpBookName</key>\
<string>com.jthink.songkong.Help</string>
' /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

but get error

```
sed: 1: "/Applications/SongKong. ...": invalid command code S
```

and I tried the bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read line; do
      echo "$line"
      if [[ "$line" = "<string>1.0</string>"]]; then
        cat mergefile.txt    # or echo or printf your extra lines
      fi
    done < /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

but got error

```
./buildosx4.sh: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
./buildosx4.sh: line 5: syntax error near `;'
./buildosx4.sh: line 5: `  if [[ "$line" = "<string>1.0</string>"]]; then'
```

**EDIT 2**
Now working, i was missing a space

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read line; do
      echo "$line"
      if [[ "$line" = "<string>1.0</string>" ]]; then
        cat mergefile.txt    # or echo or printf your extra lines
      fi
    done < /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: ***How*** is this file auto-generated? Can you fix the generator?

Comment: No I cant, the generator is not provided by me, maybe in the longterm it will be fixed (I have raised an issue ) but not in the short term.

Comment: Did you try searching? This is a very common question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to look at this is that you want to *merge* two files at some point in one of the files.  If your extra four lines were in a separate file, you could make a more generic tool like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
  SEARCH=ARGV[1];    # Get the search string from the command line
  delete ARGV[1];    # Delete the argument, so subsequent arguments are files
}

# Collect the contents of the first file into a variable
NR==FNR { 
  ins=ins $0 "\n";
  next;
}

1    # print every line in the second (or rather the non-first) file

# Once we're in the second file, if we see the match, print stuff...
$0==SEARCH {
  printf("%s", ins);    # Using printf instead of print to avoid the extra newline
  next;
}
```

I've spelled this out for ease of documentation; you could obviously shorten it to something that looked more like triplee's answer.  You'd invoke this like:

```
$ scriptname "Text to match" mergefile.txt origfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Done this way, you'd have a tool that could be used to achieve this kind of merge on different files and with different text.

Alternately, you could of course do this in pure bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo "$line"
  if [[ "$line" = "matchtext" ]]; then
    cat mergefile.txt    # or echo or printf your extra lines
  fi
done < origfile.txt
```

Comment: Tried your script but got error ./buildosx4.sh: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
./buildosx4.sh: line 5: syntax error near `;'
./buildosx4.sh: line 5: `  if [[ "$line" = "<string>1.0</string>"]]; then'

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I see from your updated question that you're missing the space before the `]]`.  You need that space.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the marker line contains `fnord` and nothing else;

```
awk '1;/^fnord$/{print "foo"; print "bar";
    print "baz"; print "quux"}' input >output
```

Comment: +1 for the approach but you need a semi-colon after 1.

Comment: +1, but can be simpler: `printf "foo\nbar\n"` or even `system( "cat repl-file" )`

Answer (score 0):

use the sed 'a command with a regex for the line you need to match

```
sed -i '/the target line looks like this/ a this is line 1\
this is line 2\
this is line 3\
this is line 4
' FILENAME
```

Comment: I like this solution except I liked ghotis solution of keeping the lines in another file, can your solution be amended to take the 4 lines from a file ?

Comment: Its failing for me with error sed: 1: "/Applications/SongKong. ...": invalid command code S

Comment: This fails for Paul because `-i` is not standard `sed`.  It works in gnu `sed`, but not all `sed`.

Comment: @William Pursell - thankyou this seems to be the main problem with unix, especially linux

Comment: The problem is not with unix, but with users not paying attention to standards.  Linux is not unix.

Comment: If your search string contains a slash, you need to backslash-escape it, or use an alternate separator. `sed '\%<string>1\.0</string>% a...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved efficiently for any filesize by this algorithm:

1. Read each line from the original file and print it to a tempfile.
2. If the last line was the marker line, print your insertion lines to the tempfile
3. Print the remaining lines
4. Rename the tempfile to the original filename.

As a Perl script:

```
#!perl
use strict; use warnings;

$^I = ".bak"; # create a backup file

while (<>) {
  print;
  last if /regex to determine if this is the line/;
}

print <<'END';
Yourstuff
END

print while <>; # print remaining lines
# renaming automatically done.
```

Testfile:

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
quux
```

Regex is `/^ba/`.

Usage: `$ perl this_script.pl source-file`

The testfile after processing:

```
foo
bar
Yourstuff
baz
qux
quux
```

Comment: well, there you go: perl, awk, or sed. take your pick!

Comment: You should probably escape the target regex to avoid meta characters being evaluated.